# Trying to export tickets/incidents from SCSM to csv file using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to do a simple ticket/incident file export using PowerShell. All of our tickets go into the Service manager 2019 Console.

What I am trying to do is be able to filter and export our tickets using certain date range.  Our senior system engineer was able to help me get started and I am trying to figure out the best way to do this.  So this is what he sent me:

**____________________________________________
you always want to filter / where as far left as possible to reduce processing overhead
also Tab is your friend when typing cmdlets - usually something like
`Get-SCSMIncident -<Tab>`
and it will show you your options
or `Get-SCSMIncident -Help`
you can also use Where-Object to filter once you have the correct subitems
`Get-SCSMIncident | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Active"}`
because you're doing the filter AFTER Get-SCSMIncident, it's going to find ALL incidents in the background, THEN filter them (slow/bad)
____________________________________________**

So I tried a few things.  He suggested to do the following below, create variables, store them and pull the data later.

`$allincidents = Get-SCSMIncident`
`$resolved = $allincdients | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Resolved"}`
`$active = $allincdients | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Active"`

Then I would export the info such as below to a csv file

`$active | export-csv c:\temp\scsm_incidents.csv -nti`

The issue is that when I execute it, the initial storing of the variables it is taking too long, because we have obviously thousands and thousands of tickets.

**I then thought what if I did the following below**
Create the date variables first and store them.

`$startDate = Get-Date -Year 2022 -Month 1 -Day 1`

`$endDate = Get-Date -Year 2022 -Month 2 -Day 2`

`Get-SCSMIncident | Where-Object {($_.createddate.date -le $endDate) -and ($_.createddate.date -ge $startDate)} | Export-Csv C:\Temp\SCSM-tickets.csv -nti`

And given the logic that my Senior Engineer told me, it is going through all the tickets first because of the Get-SCSMIncident and then filtering and then storing into an csv file.

So my question is there a way to sort of go backwards?  I know computer language wise it wouldn't make sense because it doesn't know what object it is being pointed to.

Like for example

`Where-Object {($_.createddate.date -le $endDate) -and ($_.createddate.date -ge $startDate)} |  Get-SCSMIncident | Export-Csv C:\Temp\SCSM-tickets.csv -nti`

The end result is that I want to be able to pull data on a weekly basis using just a date range, without have to run through all the tickets every time.  Since new tickets are being generated everyday, each time I run through it, it will take longer and longer and longer.  I am by no means expert with powershell at all and looking for any insight on export data files much simpler or faster.  If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it.

FYI I know I can pull each ticket at a time, our naming scheme used is INC##### so for example to pull any ticket

`Get-SCSMIncident -id "INC10105"`

This would pull up this one ticket in powershell.
I don't know all the powershell commands and searching through the library is confusing

If anyone knows a way of how to do something like this pulling tickets in sets that would be helpful.

`Get-SCSMIncident -id "INC00001" TO -id "INC00500" | Export-Csv C:\Temp\SCSM-tickets.csv -nti`

Or evening pulling data by date.

Apologize for the super long post.  Also if anyone knows how to export tickets in Service Manager Console please let me know too!!!  I searched everywhere and seems like I can't export anything

Comment: Unless `Get-SCSMIncident` has filtering by date range capabilities it is likely you will need to go through all the incidents, hence `Where-Object` is one of your options, there are faster collection filtering methods such as PowerShell `filter` or a `foreach` loop + and `if` condition could make the script go faster.

Comment: Update* I exported one INC to an csv and it exported everything, which is what I don't need, text, comments notes, etc.

I also found this online which sets the information of only the objects.  So going off base the command below is there a way to filter in small chucks?

`get-scsmincident | Select-Object -Property ID, Status, Title, @{l='Description';e={$_.Description -replace "n"," "}}, AffectedUser, AssignedTo, CreatedDate, TierQueue, Urgency, Priority | export-csv C:\temp\SCSM_Incidents.csv -nti`

Comment: Does `Get-SCSMIncident` have any documentation where it states it can filter by DateTime ranges?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon that I do not know.  I would have to ask our senior engineer.  My guess from the top of my head is no.  But as you stated, I believe I would have to go through all the incidents for now.  Might take a while, but at least I don't have to run it every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comments, unless the cmdlet `Get-SCSMIncident` has filtering by `DateTime` range capabilities, it is unlikely that there is a way around having to go through **all the collection**, however, there are ways the code could be improved so it can do the filtering faster. A `foreach` loop (enumeration) loop in addition to an `if` condition (filtering condition) is much faster than `Where-Object`.

```sh
$startDate = Get-Date -Year 2022 -Month 1 -Day 1
$endDate = Get-Date -Year 2022 -Month 2 -Day 2

$incs = foreach($inc in Get-SCSMIncident)
{
    if($inc.CreatedDate -gt $endDate -or $inc.CreatedDate -lt $startDate)
    {
        # If the Incident's CreatedDate is greater than `$endDate` OR
        # lower than `$startDate` go to the next Incident.
        # In other words, skip this Incident.
        continue
    }

    [pscustomobjct]@{
        ID           = $inc.ID
        Status       = $inc.Status
        Title        = $inc.Title
        Description  = $inc.Description -replace '\r?\n', ' '
        AffectedUser = $inc.AffectedUser
        AssignedTo   = $inc.AssignedTo
        CreatedDate  = $inc.CreatedDate
        TierQueue    = $inc.TierQueue
        Urgency      = $inc.Urgency
        Priority     = $inc.Properity
    }
}

$incs | Export-Csv path/to/exported.csv -NoTypeInformation
```